# How to prevent loading the source table repeatedly in enumeration?

Tags: ssis

I posted a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549628/dont-load-the-source-table-everytime-in-ssis), but it seems that I did not explain clearly, so I am posting it again to explain my purpose.

I have millions of rows in my source table, and I extract data from flat file to SQL DB.

[image]

To add the derived column, I use the `foreach` loop to enumerate(ADO recordset) variables I need, like ID in (345,789,809,686).

[image]

So, if I have one million rows, it will enumerate one million times to find the value I need! Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there any way to replace the foreach loop?

Comment: What is the goal? Are you trying to see if the current record in the flat file already exists in the table of millions? If so, use a lookup instead of derived column and there is no need to loop.

Comment: Or better yet, load the flat file to a temp table and do a MERGE in execute SQL (or a stored proc)

Comment: What is your Derived Column formula? What are the variables you need to enumerate? I'm going to be straight with you, this question is not much better than the one you posted yesterday. You're not telling us what you're trying to accomplish. We need more details to understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to add a surrogate key/identity to the data from the file, a Derived Column transformation isn't going to do it as a Derived Column can only see the current row - there's no facility for inspection of the previous or subsequent rows.

If you're attempting to add say an identifier metric, like data source load id, which might make sense given that you're looping over something in a foreach loop container.

You question indicates

> if I have one million rows, it will enumerate one million times to find the value I need

If you know what value you're looking for, then instead of using a foreach enumerator, just get the value from the source (process not pictured so I don't know if that's a reasonable thing).

If you're literally applying all the values in your ADO recordset to all the rows in a flat file and then stuffing it into a table - again, all we can see from both questions and what you've provided, then you have a cross join/cartesian product so in SSIS terms, you're likely looking for a... Script Component acting in asynchronous mode within your Data Flow and then you can eliminate the processing that populates the ADO.net recordset and the foreach loop container and just in-line that into the data flow.

But we need more details about the core problem you're trying to solve, what data sources/destinations you're working with. How the searching/filtering *should* behave, etc.